# How to Obtain Cumulative Triangle in R

Tags: r

I have a question. I need to obtain cumulative triangle on R Studio.

Now I have a data as follows. It's incremental.

```
AccidentYear <- c(2010,2011,2012)
Dev0 <- c(100,50,70)
Dev1 <- c(0,30,0)
Dev2 <-c(50,0,0)
IncrementalCL <- data.frame(AccidentYear,Dev0,Dev1,Dev2)
```

I need to make it cumulative. If I'd like to explain the cumulative situation of triangles, summing the values should be ended at the diagonal. This is the most significant rule of this situation. I can replace AccidenYear values with numbers like 0,1,2...

so I have to get a result like the one below.

```
DevC0 <- c(100,50,70)
DevC1 <- c(100,80,0)
DevC2 <-c(150,0,0)
CumulativeCL <- data.frame(AccidentYear,DevC0,DevC1,DevC2)
```

edit:

If the numeric values like Dev0 starts from 4th column. What should I do?

```
AccidentYear <- c(2010,2011,2012)
Information1 <- c("Info1","Info2","Info3")
Information2 <- c("Info1","Info2","Info3")
Dev0 <- c(100,50,70)
Dev1 <- c(0,30,0)
Dev2 <-c(50,0,0)
IncrementalCL <- data.frame(AccidentYear,Information1,Information2,Dev0,Dev1,Dev2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R solution:

```
x <- t(apply(IncrementalCL[-1], 1, cumsum))
x[lower.tri(x)[, ncol(x):1]] <- 0
IncrementalCL[-1] <- x
IncrementalCL

#   AccidentYear Dev0 Dev1 Dev2
# 1         2010  100  100  150
# 2         2011   50   80    0
# 3         2012   70    0    0
```

Comment: Did you use CumulativeCL as data instead of IncrementalCL?

Comment: @SeqenenreTao I start with `IncrementalCL`. What's wrong?

Comment: I was wrong sorry. Thank you for your kind reply. If the Dev0 stated at 3th colum, how should I edit the formula? I mean Dev0 start from 3th column.

Comment: @SeqenenreTao just change `IncrementalCL[-1]` at the first and third line to `IncrementalCL[-(1:2)]`

Comment: I obtained the same data. Nothing has change with this: 
x <- t(apply(IncrementalCL[-(1:2)], 1, cumsum))
x[lower.tri(x)[, ncol(x):1]] <- 0
IncrementalCL[-1] <- x
IncrementalCL

Comment: @SeqenenreTao I said change `IncrementalCL[-1]` at the **first** and **third** line. You only change the first line.

Comment: Thank you for you kind replies @Darren Tsai

If the AccidentYear column is not sorted, what should we do? As with the previous case, the aggregation will stop at AccPeriod + Dev..

    AccidentYear <- c(2010,2013,2011,2012)
    AccPeriod <-c(0,3,1,2)
    Information1 <- c("Info1","Info2","Info3","Info4")
    Dev0<-c(100,40,50,0)
    Dev1<-c(0,0,50,0)
    Dev2<-c(50,0,0,0)
    Dev3<-c(0,0,0,0)
    IncrementalCL<-data.frame(AccidentYear,AccPeriod,Information1,Dev0,Dev1,Dev2,Dev3)

Comment: I can not "order" the values. Because I'm doing it on 10mio rows data and there are lots of each AccPeriod. Where the aggrigation stops should change in each row.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect. With the data I use in my answer, can you show the expected output to me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213805/discussion-between-seqenenre-tao-and-darren-tsai).